# ROS can't access iRobot Create

Tags: ros, irobot-create, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to work on iRobot Create. I used the ROS drivers following instructions from the Wiki (Turtlebot_node and irobot_create_2_1)

But, while I was trying to run the python script, an error message popped up saying that irobot create isn't connected into the computer. I am using PL-2303X/H serial port and I plugged the cable accordingly with setting the permission (sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0). Is there any driver source I have to install in Ubuntu 12.04 (Kernel  3.5.0-42-generic) for using PL-2303X/H? Any suggestions?

The error message is as follows

Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0. Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103076/ros-can%27t-access-irobot-create/) by [game4cesc](https://answers.ros.org/users/9006/game4cesc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are getting errors like that you still have permissions issues on the USB port.  Using chmod is not persistent across reboots.  A more permenant solution is to use udev rules or add yourself to the default group for the port.

There are also several other questions about the irobot Create that talk about bad USB adapters. http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/page:1/query:irobot/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [game4cesc](https://answers.ros.org/users/9006/game4cesc/) on 2013-11-20**:
Thanks for the quick reply and the link for the related questions. I do set the permission in /etc/udev/rules.d directory and I'm already in the default group. Is there any way PL-2303X/H serial port can connect the iRobot Create with a computer? Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-20**:
One other person had problems with this adapter and ended up just buying a different one: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1716756.html has the results.